# Get Module ID or Title

Tags: joomla

I' am using Joomla 3, I have module called "**Who we Are**" and it's being displayed on position "**top_row2**". I' am trying to get this modules ID and modules Name.

After Searching I found few solutions which doesn't seem to work for me.

**Solution 1**

```
jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule('Who we Are');
echo $module->id;
```

**Solution 2**

```
jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );
$module = JModuleHelper::getModules('Who we Are');
echo $module->id;
//Note the "s" in getModules
```

**Solution 3**

```
    global $module;
    $module->id;
    $module->title;
```

I' am using this solutions on the override PHP files of this Module.

**Location::** templates\corporate_response\html\mod_mymodule_item.php

Comment: Where are you adding this code to?

Comment: @Lodder on my override HTML Module Folder, please see my updated question above for the location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define your own unique Class under "Module Class Suffix" and in your module override item page do a conditional to check which module is being rendered into the page

Answer (score 1):

This might help explain calling modules in overrides.
To call a Joomla! module with the title in a template override:

```
jimport('joomla.application.module.helper');
$modules = JModuleHelper::getModules('position');
foreach($modules as $module) {
echo '<h3>' . $module->title . '</h3>';
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module);
}
```

This will call the module id.

```
echo $module->id;
```

This will call the module title in H3, adjust to what you need.

```
echo '<h3>' . $module->title . '</h3>';
```

This part will render the module.

```
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all modules by position and then select by title like this:

```
$module = false;
if ($modules = JModuleHelper::getModules('top_row2')) {
    foreach ($modules as $module2) {
        if ($module2->title == 'Who we Are') {
            $module = $module2;
            break;
        }
    }
}

if ($module) {
    printf(
        'Found module with name "%s" and id "%d"',
        $module->name,
        $module->id
    );
} else {
    echo "Found no matching module.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone ever has the same question:

Within the modules code you can simply use the variable `$module` which contains all information about this specific module like `id`, `title`, `position`, ...